# fish won't return specified status code from function with "return"

Tags: scripting, fish

I was using this simple function for reusable user confirmation in my other functions:

```sh
function read_confirm --description 'Ask the user for confirmation' --argument prompt
    if test -z "$prompt"
        set prompt "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: "
    end 

    while true
        read -l -P $prompt confirm
        switch $confirm
        case N n
            return 1
        case '' Y y
            return 0
        end
    end
end
```

This worked fine in previous version, however now when I installed version **3.0.0**, it seems that I am always getting status code of 0.

```sh
 ~ read_confirm
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]:
 ~ echo $status
0
 ~ read_confirm
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: y
 ~ echo $status
0
 ~ read_confirm
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: Y
 ~ echo $status
0
 ~ read_confirm
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: n
 ~ echo $status
0
 ~ read_confirm
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: N
 ~ echo $status
0
 ~
```

At first I thought that the case statement doesn't work, however user input is properly read, it doesn't have leading '\n', it will go to 'N n' case, function will properly "finish", however "return 1" always set status to 0 and I can't figure out why. Did the fish API changed? am I simly using it wrong and need to rewrite it?

UPDATE:
Created a bug report as this is regresion from previous versions
https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5600

Thanks for help,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, will be fixed in the next dot release. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5513